# Custom Module in Magento 1.5 hangs while browsing grid

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I have Magento 1.5 installed and am working on this tutorial http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table

After getting the backend and front end working, I got to work on adding in the custom objects which belong to the custom module. The objects are added just fine. The objects can be edited, saved and deleted just fine. When trying to search or browse beyond the first page however, the Please Wait Loader appears on the screen and hangs. Behind the loader one can see that the next page / search results page is loading the objects and displaying them correctly, however the loader won't close and it leaves the page inaccessible. Firebug's console isn't reporting any errors and when I check the post information in the console, it shows the proper html for the table, rows and objects is being returned.

I've checked the error logs for the server as well as the error logs for magento and there are no errors being shown (outside of the past errors in getting the tutorial to work in the first place).

Any help would be so very much appreciated.

Comment: If it matters, the custom module is a list of external websites which sell our companies products. There is 4 fields - store_id, store_name, store_url, and store_status. Store status is a normal magento active/inactive drop down box.

Comment: Have you tried using firebug for firefox or some other browser's debugging tool to see if there is an error message in ajax response?

Comment: Yea I used firebug and the POST response is coming back valid and complete.

Comment: ugh, minified compiled JS from dozens of individual libraries and script files is not fun to breakpoint...

Comment: So my coworker noticed that the CMS-Store Locator module didn't use some of the grid functions or ajax and didn't use the loaderbox as well. We turned off the ajax and grid functions and there's no longer a problem. Not a real solution but it solves our problem.

Answer (score 0):

remove the useAjax in the __construct and remove the getGridUrl function from your Grid.php. Remove the gridAction from the admin controller to stop that ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and now it is resolved.

Step1. Add below code to Grid.php

```
    /**
     * Define row click callback
     */
    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=>true));
    }
```

Step2. Add below code to yourController.php (i.e. adminhtml controller)

```
 /**
     * Render grid
     */
    public function gridAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
```

Step2. Add below code to layout.xml (i.e. adminhtml layout)

```
    <adminhtml_yourContoller_grid>
        <remove name="root"/>
        <block type="yourModule/adminhtml_yourBlock_grid" name="name_grid" output="toHtml"/>
    </adminhtml_yourContoller_grid>
```